# python pandas standardize column for regression

Tags: python, pandas, scale, normalize, standardized

I have the following df:

```
Date       Event_Counts   Category_A  Category_B
20170401      982457          0           1
20170402      982754          1           0
20170402      875786          0           1
```

I am preparing the data for a regression analysis and want to standardize the column Event_Counts, so that it's on a similar scale like the categories.

I use the following code:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
df['scaled_event_counts'] = preprocessing.scale(df['Event_Counts'])
```

While I do get this warning:

```
DataConversionWarning: Data with input dtype int64 was converted to float64 by the scale function.
  warnings.warn(msg, _DataConversionWarning)
```

it seems to have worked; there is a new column. However, it has negative numbers like -1.3

What I thought the scale function does is subtract the mean from the number and divide it by the standard deviation for every row; then add the min of the result to every row.

Does it not work for pandas that way? Or should I use the normalize() function or StandardScaler() function? I wanted to have the standardize column on a scale of 0 to 1.

Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [`sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler). That will allow you to scale to a given range.

So in your case it would be:

```
scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
df['scaled_event_counts'] = scaler.fit_transform(df['Event_Counts'])
```

To scale the entire df:

```
scaled_df = scaler.fit_transform(df)
print(scaled_df)
[[ 0.          0.99722347  0.          1.        ]
 [ 1.          1.          1.          0.        ]
 [ 1.          0.          0.          1.        ]]
```

Comment: interesting! I didn't know that exists, let me try that

Comment: I'm getting this error with a different column DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and will raise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Comment: I believe you can apply this method to the entire dataframe

Comment: I already have many columns in 0/1 format; so I wasn't going to use it on the whole df

Comment: I don't believe it will impact columns that are already scaled to your range

Answer (score 1):

Scaling is done by subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation of each feature (column). So,

```
scaled_event_counts = (Event_Counts - mean(Event_Counts)) / std(Event_Counts)
```

The int64 to float64 warning comes from having to subtract the mean, which would be a floating point number, and not just an integer.

You will have negative numbers with the scaled column because the mean will be normalized to zero.

Comment: thank you; and scale() from preprocessing does exactly that?

Comment: Yes. If you'd like, the source is available [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.18.1/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py#L80).