# Python DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and will raise ValueError in 0.19

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, deprecation-warning

Based on my previous question [python pandas standardize column for regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43458593/python-pandas-standardize-column-for-regression) I am rescaling specific columns in my dataframe to be between 0 and 1.

```
scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
email['scaled_quantity'] = scaler.fit_transform(email['Quantity'])
```

Unfortunately, I get this error

```
DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and will raise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
  warnings.warn(DEPRECATION_MSG_1D, DeprecationWarning)
```

@Grr proposed that I apply the scaling to the whole dataframe, but that is not an option. I need to maintain the columns the way they are and only want to add new additional scaled columns.

How can I address this depreciation error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what about doing

```
scaler.fit_transform(email[['Quantity']])
```

instead of

```
scaler.fit_transform(email['Quantity'])
```

**Demo**: i used your sample data set from the previous question:

```
In [56]: scaler.fit_transform(df[['Event_Counts']])
Out[56]:
array([[ 0.99722347],
       [ 1.        ],
       [ 0.        ]])
```

Notice - it produced an array with the shape `(3,1)` instead of `(3,)`

as a new column:

```
In [58]: df['scaled_event_counts'] = scaler.fit_transform(df[['Event_Counts']])

In [59]: df
Out[59]:
       Date  Event_Counts  Category_A  Category_B  scaled_event_counts
0  20170401        982457           0           1             0.997223
1  20170402        982754           1           0             1.000000
2  20170402        875786           0           1             0.000000
```

Comment: thank you; do you mind explaining to me the difference?

Comment: @jeangelj Just to explain the difference. If you pass a 1d array, then it creates a ambiguity in model as to how to interpret it. To take it as one sample [1, n_features] or to take it as multiple samples with 1 feature each [n_samples, 1]. Hope this makes things clear